# Nginx upstream configuration always giving 404

Tags: nginx, wordpress, node.js

I am setting up nginx for a website and I want it to route to 3 locations - the main frontend server, api server and to the wordpress blog server. I can get it working for the frontend server and wordpress, but the upstream api server is always giving 404 when accessing the API's via the frontend. The wordpress is running on port `8080`, while the 2 NodeJS servers are running on `8015` & `8016`. While hitting `mysite.com` frontend server on `8015` shows up the UI, but on calling the login API on port `8016` it throws 404 error. `mysite.com/blog` shows up the Worpress Blog after rewriting the url to `mysite.com:8080`

The nginx config is given:

```
upstream backend {
    server <IP>:8016
}

server {
   listen 80;


  server_name mysite.com;
  location / {

    root /code/public;
    index index.html
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

  }

  location /api/{
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://backend/;
  }

  location /blog {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location ~\.php$ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://<IP>:8080;
  }

  location~/\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: First, you have a space after http:. Then, is the 404 error generated by nginx or node?

Comment: sorry that is a typo. correcting it. 404 is generated by nginx